# ASP.NET MVC 4.5 routing to root url causes HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to route to the root of my site to the index action of my default controller.
While I feel that this is very basic, none of the related questions seemed to solve my issue.

I have tried

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default", // Route name
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
            defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
```

and

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Homepage",
            url: "",
            defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index" }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default", // Route name
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
            defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

But both give me an error when I try to view the site at localhost:57101/ by pressing f5

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
>
> Most likely causes: A default document is not configured for the
>   requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.
>
> Things you can try: If you do not want to enable directory browsing,
>   ensure that a default document is configured and that the file exists.
>   Enable directory browsing. Go to the IIS Express install directory.
>   Run appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse
>   /enabled:true to enable directory browsing at the server level. Run
>   appcmd set config ["SITE_NAME"]
>   /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true to enable
>   directory browsing at the site level. Verify that the
>   configuration/system.webServer/directoryBrowse@enabled attribute is
>   set to true in the site or application configuration file.

localhost:57101/Default
and localhost:57101/Default/Index both correctly route to the index action of my default controller. It is only the root that gives me this error.

I am using VS 2013 Express with the built in web server.  I have only one controller and action.

This is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false"></add>

    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Your routing looks fine which means there is probably something else conflicting. Do you have a folder/file called default or anything like that?

Comment: No, I don't. The project structure was created by the blank project template, and contains folders for views, controllers, scripts, images, and css. I played with the nuget packages and changed the view code, but that's pretty much it so far.

Comment: Odd, I can't replicate it. As an experiment, what happens if you rename the controller to something else?

Comment: I changed the name of the default controller to 'test'. 
The definition is now public class TestController : Controller
When I tried to browse to localhost:57101/Test I got the error
Server Error in '/' Application.

The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
[List of locations]
This was before and after I changed the instances of Default to Test in Global.asax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was what the problem turned out to be:
When I created my project from a template there was a RouteConfig under App_Start, which was actually being used instead of the RegisterRoutes method in Global.asax.

Here is what was in that file

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

I changed it to what was in my global.asax and deleted that method from global.asax

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

It turns out that I didn't know where my routes were actually defined. I thought that I was setting my default controller to Default because it was in the global.asax file, but there was actually a file that overrides that in App_start/RouteConfig

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, but ultimately my issue/solution was described in the comment above by DavidG -

*Your routing looks fine which means there is probably something else conflicting. Do you have a folder/file called default or anything like that? – DavidG Jul 23 '14 at 14:54*

I was getting 403'd only when viewing the root of my Reports controller, but not if I specified the view.

So, /Reports would 403, /Reports/WeeklyReport would return correctly.

The issue source was that I had a folder to house generated reports under the root of the application called, Reports. I renamed this "extra" Reports folder and no more 403.

Hopefully this helps someone down the road.